# Why does my Svelte store subscribe() get fired when the value hasn't changed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I have a Svelte store `activeAccountIndexStore`:

```
export const activeAccountIndexStore: Writable<number | "native" | null> =
  writable(null);
```

The original value is `null` but after some network activity it will be set to a specific `number` or the `string` 'native'.

I also have a `subscribe()` handler for the store, that is called from other Svelte components:

```js
export const onChangeActiveAccount = (
  activeAccountHandler: ActiveAccountHandler
) => {
  activeAccountIndexStore.subscribe((newValue) => {
    log(`➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value`, newValue);
    if (newValue !== null) {
      const activeAccount = getActiveAccount();
      activeAccountHandler(activeAccount);
    }
  });
};
```

The odd thing is, the `subscribe()` change handler is being called repeatedly, even though the store has the same value in subsequent changes:

```
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value null
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value null
2stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value 0
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value 0
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value 0
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value 0
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value 0
```

[MDNs Svelte docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_stores) state:

> A store is an object with a subscribe() method that allows interested parties to be notified whenever the store value changes.

But the value is not changing in many of the cases above. I would have expected to see:

```
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value null
stores.ts:68 ➡️➡️➡️➡️➡️ activeAccountIndexStore new value 0
```

**Why does my Svelte store subscribe() get fired when the value hasn't changed?**

Comment: It has to do with `re-evaluation` of your `Svelte components`

Comment: Yes exactly,  
IMO the solution is to find someway to `memoize` the component `state`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with re-evaluation of your Svelte components. If you're subscribing to a store inside a component, and instances of the component are being created and destroyed, the subscribe event will fire because **the value is new for this instance of the component**.

Re-evaluation of the component could happen if it gets unmounted, and re-mounted, or if the component is receiving new state.

A simple solution for this is to memoize the component state, eg do the `.subscribe()` outside of the component.

Comment: Thanks again! I've tweaked the markdown a little and added some of the bits of our discussion to the answer. I hope that's OK.